# How can I make images show up in the correct scale when printing an HTML page as PDF?

Tags: html, css, image, pdf

I have a web page which is meant to be printed as a PDF.  Everything looks great until I get to a page which shows images.  For reasons unknown to me, the width of the images seem fine but the height is too high when appearing in the PDF preview.

The HTML looks like this:

```
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Top Depth Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.TopDepthImageUri" width="512" height="384" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Bottom Depth Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.BottomDepthUri" width="512" height="384" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Finish Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.FinishImageUri" width="512" height="384" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Area Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.AreaImageUri" width="512" height="384" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

On the web page the images look fine, but when I print the PDF preview looks like this:

[image]

You can see that only one row of the table is shown and the images are not scaled as they should be.  (The second row was on the following page.)

How can I control the exact height and width of the image in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Top Depth Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.TopDepthImageUri" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Bottom Depth Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.BottomDepthUrig" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Finish Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.FinishImageUri" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%" class="centerText">
                            <span style="font-size:small;text-align: center;">Area Photo</span>
                            <img src="@utility.AreaImageUri" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```